# Updating JavaScript Object with HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I am building a Star Wars based rpg. In the first part of the game I am trying to ask the user to pick a side (rebels/empire) to play as. I have two divs that contain images with each respective sides logo. So for example, if the user clicks the empire logo they will play as the Empire. If I make a soldier prototype in JavaScript, how would I update the properties in the soldier object if the user clicks on a certain div/image? The only advice I've received is that it would be easier to do in jQuery? I can't seem to figure it out but this is what I have:

```
<body>
<h2>Choose Your Side</h2>
<div class="rebels">
<div onclick="chooseSide()">
<img id="logo" src="../img/rebels.jpg" alt="Rebels" height="320" width="380">
</div>
</div>
<div class="empire">
<div onclick="chooseSide()">
<img id="logo" src="../img/empire.jpg" alt="Empire" height="300" width="300">
</div>
</div>

function soldier(side, weapon, sidearm) {
this.side = function chooseSide() {
    //code here
}
}
```

Comment: `chooseSide('rebels')` - pass in a function argument?

Comment: the choosSide() function isn't in the global scope. It is in the soldier function. You would need to create a variable instance e.g. 'Soldier' of the soldier and have it accessible globally. Then the onclick will need to call the variable like 'Solder.chooseSide()'

Comment: Boo global variables! Boo!

Comment: Why not use `eventListener`s? That way you can pass either 'rebels' or 'empire' depending on the image that is clicked.

Comment: Realize I'm likely wasting my breath but *strongly* recommend picking something less ambitious as a first project. Or tenth project.

Comment: @JaredSmith I have a feeling we will see a lot more posts here from the OP

Comment: You can't have two identical `ID`s on the same HTML page. It's not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Prueba</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

         var soldier = {
            "side" : ""
         }

        function chooseSide(object){
            var alt = object.childNodes[1].alt
            soldier.side = alt;
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Choose Your Side</h2>
<div class="rebels">
<div onclick="chooseSide(this)" style="background-color: red; height: 20px;">
    <img id="logo" src="../img/rebels.jpg" alt="Rebels" height="320" width="380"/>
</div>
</div>

<div class="empire">
<div onclick="chooseSide(this)" style="background-color: blue; height: 20px;">
    <img id="logo" src="../img/empire.jpg" alt="Empire" height="300" width="300"/>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an object as follows to store the player's, in this case the soldier's properties.

e.g.

```
var soldier = {

}
```

You could then say:

```
function chooseSide(side) {
    soldier["side"] = side;
}
```

The soldier object would then look like:

```
{
    side: "rebels/empire"
}
```

Later in your code you could access you soldier's side by saying:

```
console.log(soldier.side);
// Obviously this is just a print to the console, but you can anything with it
```

**Also, as stated in the comments, when you call the function in your `onclick` event you need to pass in some value, such as "rebels". I also do not see the need for you soldier function.

**This will only create one instance of the soldier.

Comment: Why use the square bracket notation and not the dot notation?

Comment: It is a preference. I need to use that notation for using variable names as object keys so I just stick with that convention so my code is similar across the board.

Comment: Okay... For me, dot notation is my preferred (it looks neater to me). Unless I need computed property names or I am accessing an array.

Comment: Use it as you please. If you have any more questions related to the problem just ask.